# Issue with "number_format" property in Taipy table rendering

Tags: python, user-interface, format, taipy

How to use the "number_format" property in Taipy [table](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/table/)? The documentation doesn't say anything on this subject.

I expected something like `.2f` to show two decimals, but whatever I write here is just reproduced as plain text in the table.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui 

data = {"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[1.3355,2.674,3.4546,4.456]}

Gui('<|{data}|table|number_format=.2f|>').run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a '%' before '.2f'. This should be the proper syntax.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui 

data = {"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[1.3355,2.674,3.4546,4.456]}

Gui('<|{data}|table|number_format=%.2f|>').run()
```

[image: result]